# If $\partial X\subset Y$, then $X\cup Y$ is connnected.

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

> Let $X,Y$ and $M$ connnected. If $\partial X\subset Y$, then $X\cup Y$ is connected.

My approach: I know that the boundary of set $X$ is equal to $\partial X=\bar X\setminus int(X)=\bar X\cap(M-int(X))\subset Y$, but if $X$ is connected I dont know how this implies that $X\cup Y$ is connected. Regards!

Answer (score 5):

Towards a straightforward proof, you could use the characterization that a space is connected iff the only integer-valued continuous maps on it are the constant ones.

Let $f$: $X\cup Y\longrightarrow\{0; 1\}$ be continuous. Since $X$ is connected, $f$ is constant on $X$, wlog. $f=0$ there. Since $\partial X\subset Y$, we still have $f=0$ on $\overline{X}$ by continuity. But $\partial X\cap Y\neq\emptyset$, so by connectedness of $Y$ we have $f=0$ on $X\cup Y$.

Comment: I know that, if $X$ is connected, then $\bar X$ is also connected, but I missed when you mentioned "But $\partial X\cap Y\neq \emptyset$..." Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Ahna Akbar It is given that $\partial X \subset Y$, so of course $\partial X \cap Y $ is not empty.